# What do I need to manipulate to get my status bars in the correct position?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi I'm a newb at html and css. Also using bootstrap4. I'm trying to get a couple status bars around my pip boy. I am trying to make them look like the first image, but I am having trouble getting them to look like that. What do I need to adjust in order to move the status bars closer to the pip boy? Margin, padding, or border?

[image: what I want mine to look like]

[image: my pip boy]

**html**

```
                     <div class="stat-bars">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                        <div class="level-progress"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="stat-bar">
                                        <div class="level-progress"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="stat-bar">
                                        <div class="level-progress"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="stat-bar">
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="stat-bar">
                                        <div class="level-progress"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="stat-bar">
                                        <div class="level-progress"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="stat-bar">
                                <div class="level-progress"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                        <div class="tab-pane" id="special" role="tabpanel">
                            special
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="perks" role="tabpanel">
                            perks
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**stylesheet**

```
@font-face{
    font-family: Pipboy;
    src:url('../monofonto.ttf');
}


body{
    font-family:Pipboy, sans-serif;
    color:#14fe17;
    background-color: #292f26 !important;
}

body::after{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    background:repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,.5), rgba(0,0,0,.04) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 2px);
    opacity: .3;
    z-index: 1000000;
    pointer-events:none;

}

.navbar{
    border-bottom:2px solid;
    margin:0px 10px;
}

.navbar.navbar-light::before, .navbar.navbar-light::after{
    height: 5px;
    width: 2px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 5000;
    background:#14fe17;;
    bottom: -7px;
}

.navbar::before {
    left:0px;
}


.navbar::after{
    right:0px;
}



ul > li.nav-item > a.nav-link, ul > li.navbar-item.active > a.nav-link {
    color:#14fe17 !important;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-item.active::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: #f00;
    width: 100%;
    height: 26px;
    top: 14px;
    background: #272b23;
    border-left: 2px solid;
    border-right: 2px solid;
    border-top: 2px solid;
    left: 0px;

}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav > li.navbar-item.active > .nav-link{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 50;
    position: relative;
    background: #262b23
}

.navbar-nav{
    width:100%;
}

.navbar-light ul.navbar-nav > li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 10%;
}

.center-image{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 400px;
}

.center-image img{

    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 300px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    filter:grayscale(1)sepia(100%)hue-rotate(55deg)saturate(7)brightness(1)contrast(2);
}

.pip-footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    margin: 0px;
}

.navbar.navbar-light .navbar-nav{
    margin: 0px 200px;
}

.navbar.navbar-light .navbar-nav > li {
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav.nav-tabs{
    margin:20px;
    border-bottom:none;
}

.nav.nav-tabs > .nav-item > .nav-link:hover{
    border:1px solid transparent;
}

.nav.nav-tabs >li>a{

    font-size: 26px !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    border: 1px solid transparent !important;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}


.nav.nav-tabs > li:nth-child(2) >a {
    opacity: .5;
}

.nav.nav-tabs > li:nth-child(3) >a {
    opacity: .2;
}

.level-progress{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    border: 2px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%; 
}

.level-progress-indicator{

    height: 6px;
    background: #14fe16;
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;

}


.navbar.navbar-light.pip-footer{
    border:none;
}

.navbar.pip-footer .col-3, .navbar.pip-footer .col-6{
    background: rgba(16, 255, 0, 0.15);
}

.navbar.pip-footer .col-6{
    margin:0px 5px ;
    flex: 0 0 48% ;
}

.stat-bar {
    width: 60px;
    margin: auto;

}

#status P{
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}

    
.stat-bars > .row {
    margin-bottom: 125px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could change your col-6 to a lower number, then center the columns within the row by adding `justify-content-center` class to the row.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#variable-width-content